# How to create, write and read XML file in internal storage

Tags: android, xml

I am developing an android app, which accesses XML file saved on remote location when device finds internet connectivity. I want to save the file locally in my app, so that even if device doesn't have data connectivity, app can parse data from local XML file. Following is the  code i'm currently using

```
private class ListAsync extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    File path = new File(getFilesDir(),"my_data_folder");

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        Log.i("test", "Running on ui thread");
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        nameAddressList = null;
        final XMLDOMParserHandler parser = new XMLDOMParserHandler(
                tag_name.toLowerCase(), ListOfPlacesActivity.this);
        try {
            CheckConnectivity checkConnectivity = new CheckConnectivity(ListOfPlacesActivity.this);
            if (checkConnectivity.isConnectivityOn()) {
                URL myURL = new URL("http://somewebsite.com/data.xml");
                URLConnection ucon = myURL.openConnection();
                final InputStream is = ucon.getInputStream();
                try {
                    if( !path.isDirectory()) {
                        path.mkdir();
                    }
                    File dataFile = new File(path,"data.xml");
                    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(dataFile);
                    String data = getStringFromInputStream(is);
                    fos.write(data.getBytes());
                    fos.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                nameAddressList = parser.parseXML(is);
            }
            else {
                try {
                    File dataFile = new File(path,"data.xml");
                    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(dataFile);
                    DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fis);
                    nameAddressList = parser.parseXML(in);
                    in.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                nameAddressList = parser.parseXML(getInputStream("data.xml"));
            }

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ConnectException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        ListOfPlacesAdapter listOfPlacesAdapter = new ListOfPlacesAdapter(ListOfPlacesActivity.this, nameAddressList);
        listView.setAdapter(listOfPlacesAdapter);
        listView.setItemsCanFocus(true);
        spinner.dismiss();
    }

    private InputStream getInputStream(String fileName){
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        try {
            inputStream = getAssets().open(fileName);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return inputStream;
    }

    private String getStringFromInputStream(InputStream is) {

        BufferedReader br = null;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        String line;
        try {

            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (br != null) {
                try {
                    br.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        return sb.toString();

    }
}
```

Above code is not working as well as not giving error as well. Please tell where i am going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

you may consider using Android Sync adapter and do periodic/Manual sync of XML  files from your server to your local storage and vise versa. Android will take care of the sync when the network connection is available. Here is the link to the tutorial

http://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/index.html

Best approach would be to use local xml file always for your updates and sync it with the server after update and thus making sure that both client and server has the same version.  You can call the sync adapter manually after an update to the local file and that will trigger an immediate sync with the server. During the sync, if there is an Exception (EG:- Network not available) Set the sync to Retry by setting the right flag. Sync adapter will take care of the retry for you when the network is available again. When the server data changes from another user/application, send a GCM broadcast  message to your application and use that broadcast message to trigger a sync again so that your local copy gets the latest version from server. you can use timestamps to decide which one is latest

Comment: I went through above link and it has a note saying  "If you need to do real-time data transfer, you should do it in an AsyncTask or an IntentService". So I can not use Async Adapter in my code.

Comment: I think you need to change your question then. You cannot do real time data transfer with a remote machine, when your phone does not have data connectivity.

Comment: I am doing realtime dat transfer only when I have data connectivity. When there is no data connectivity, I will be reading data from File saved internally